# Observing active activity of application

Tags: android

Is it possible to observe the active activity on the Application context in any way?
how?

Comment: What is "the active activity"?

Answer (score 1):

An application can have only one active activity at a time, that activity is the one being displayed on the screen. Go through the the android activity life cycle to know more.[image]

As you can see,there are various states an activity can be in. The one that is active/visible is the one in running state.

If you have started to develop an android application in an IDE like eclipse, you can see what happens behind the scene by observing the logcat. Here is a screenshot of one of my apps, u can observe which activity is being shown to the user[image]

To know the current activity on a device i think you should probably look at the log files generated by apps like

[NE-Debugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.nedebug&hl=en)

[aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd)

[CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5ub2xhbmxhd3Nvbi5sb2djYXQiXQ..)

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer but how to do this programatically?

Comment: do u mean programming in android ? There are lot of tutorials on youtube to get you started.I recommend these Markana bootcamp series(http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE08A97D36D5A255F) & thenewboston(http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC2F07DBCDCC01493A)